# Oracle SQL Self-Join: How to include the missing record

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the NAME and PLAN even if they are no records. I tried to use self join on this one but no luck :(

script:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT    A.NAME  , B.PLAN
    FROM PLAYER A  
    LEFT JOIN PLAYER B
    ON A.NAME = B.NAME 
    WHERE A.NAME IN ( 'BOGGIE', 'STEPH')
    AND  B.PLAN IN ('PLAN200' , 'PLAN999');
```

current result

```
    NAME    PLAN
    BOOGIE  PLAN200
    STEPH   PLAN200
```

expected result

```
    NAME    PLAN
    BOOGIE  PLAN200
    BOOGIE  
    STEPH   PLAN200
    STEPH
```

TABLE

```
    NAME    PLAN    AMOUNT  CONTRACT
    BOGGIE  PLAN200   200      24
    STEPH   PLAN200   200      24
```

Comment: Please provide sample data set which would help fellow community members to propose solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using put your other condition in `ON clause`

```
SELECT DISTINCT    A.NAME  , B.PLAN
    FROM PLAYER A  
    LEFT JOIN PLAYER B
    ON A.NAME = B.NAME 
    and A.NAME IN ( 'BOGGIE', 'STEPH')
    AND  B.PLAN IN ('PLAN200' , 'PLAN999');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the query is:

`A.NAME IN ( 'BOGGIE', 'STEPH')  AND  B.PLAN IN ('PLAN200' , 'PLAN999');`

The query is putting a `left join` on `NAME`, but the records are getting further filtered after the `left join` has been applied. The where clause conditions should be correctly added in `left join` clause.

Below query should give the expected result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT    A.NAME  , B.PLAN
FROM PLAYER A 
LEFT JOIN PLAYER B
ON A.NAME = B.NAME
AND (A.NAME IN ( 'BOGGIE', 'STEPH')
OR B.PLAN IN ('PLAN200' , 'PLAN999'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data in the question is incomplete to have the desired output; please try the below. Added two rows for BOGGIE and STEPH with null plans; let us know this suffices.

```
WITH player
     AS (SELECT 'BOGGIE' name,
                'PLAN200' plan,
                200 amount,
                24 contract
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'STEPH ' name,
                'PLAN200' plan,
                200 amount,
                24 contract
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'BOGGIE' name,
                NULL plan,
                NULL amount,
                NULL contract
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'STEPH ' name,
                NULL plan,
                NULL amount,
                NULL contract
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.plan
  FROM player a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN player b
          ON     a.name = b.name
             AND (   a.name IN ('BOGGIE', 'STEPH')
                  OR b.plan IN ('PLAN200', 'PLAN999'))
```

Output

```
NAME   PLAN   
------ -------
BOGGIE PLAN200
BOGGIE        
STEPH  PLAN200
STEPH
```

Answer (score 0):

First cross join the PLAYER with the two plans --> cross_result.
Once you get that you would have result set as follows

```
cross_result
BOOGIE PLAN200
BOOGIE PLAN999
STEPH  PLAN200
STEPH  PLAN999

player
BOOGIE PLAN200
STEPH  PLAN200
```

After that left join cross_result with the PLAYER table

```
with cte
      as (SELECT 'PLAN200' as plan FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
          SELECT 'PLAN999' as plan FROM DUAL
          )
    ,cross_result  
     as (select A.PLAYER,A.PLAN
           from cte m
           join PLAYER A
             ON A.NAME IN ( 'BOGGIE', 'STEPH')
         )
   select a.PLAYER,b.PLAN /*I have choosen b.PLAN, so for a.PLAN=PLAN99 it would display null*/
     from cross_result a
left join PLAYER b
       on a.player=b.player
      and a.plan=b.plan
```